# .net non blocking IO pre 4.5

Tags: .net

Is it possible to use non blocking IO in .net 4.0 or earlier?

In other words, without using a thread and without using the async await keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The [Asynchronous Programming Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) was introduced (I believe) in .NET 1.0, and the [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx) was introduced in .NET 2.0.

`async` and `await` are a lot easier to use, though. If you're writing desktop apps, `async`/`await` can be enabled on .NET 4.0 using [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/). This would mean you're supporting XP longer than Microsoft itself does, though...